# Neural Network Stuck in local minima xor?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I currently trying to create a neural network of my own. I have managed to get the network to work to a degree but to the best of my knowledge I seem to be stuck in a local minima when I run the program or atleast output spitted out by the net seems to be changing at a very very slow pace. The pace changes/ or I get better output as I add more nodes in the hidden layer can anyone suggest or have a look at my code to see why it's not working with 2 nodes in hidden layer. And why do I have to add more node in the hidden layer for it to give decent mse.

Thank you in advance.

this is the mse at the end of 100000 iteration with 2 nodes :

> 0.07402
>   0.07402
>   0.07402

so on and on. As you can see mse should be around 0.001 but its quite high.

[link to the code!](https://github.com/sanny1/Backpropagation)

Comment: The `xor` problem is the very reason for creation of the RBF type neural networks.

Comment: Shouldn't the sigmoid type nets till solve the xor problem?

Comment: especially after 100000 iteration?

Comment: @Sad, polfosol comment is simply false, sigmoids will solve xor just fine.

Comment: @polfosol Multilayer Perceptrons with non-linear activation functions can solve XOR. In fact, they're universal approximators.

Comment: @runDOSrun You are right. But I wasn't saying that MLPs _cannot_ solve XOR. I just said that there existed some issues that led to the introduction of the RBF networks, and that XOR was among the top reasons. Now I guess the OP may have faced the same problem.

Comment: @polfosol Your comments suggest the opposite and are therefore misleading. MLPs can solve XOR without any issue and don't need 100k iterations.

Comment: @runDOSrun Just for example, take a look at the suggested same questions on the right side of the page. I don't know whether you see the same links as mine, but anyway, all of them have faced problems with XOR function in some neural networks. and that doesn't look to me like a problem _without any issues_

Comment: @polfosol There is no causality between the number of people who fail at *implementing* an algorithm and the number of people who fail to get good results with a *properly implemented* algorithm. You're suggesting the latter, OP and 90% of the questions here are about the former. Also, you're completely going off-topic.

Comment: @runDOSrun You are right about going off-topic. And other things you said are not wrong. I am not arguing anymore. Just for going back to the topic, I recommend the OP to take a look at [this](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/INC/l15.pdf) pp. 8-11

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved it all it need was bias used this link to help myself code. [link](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/neural-networks-a-multilayer-perceptron-in-matlab/#comment-181355)!